# read integer from a file

Tags: c++, file, stringstream

I'm making a program that reads the integers from a text file and shows them into the screen. I wanted to use stringstream, but i'm not sure how it works.

Text file contains also the words for example:

```
She bought a tshirt for 25 shoes for 50 and a book for 5
```

On the screen only 25, 50 and 5 should be seen. Now the output i see is just a 0.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

string file = "file.txt";

void f() {
    vector<int> num;
    ifstream ist {file};
    if (!ist) error("can't open input file", file);
    string textline;
    while (getline(ist, textline)) {
        istringstream text(textline);
        int integer;
        text >> integer;
        num.push_back(integer);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
        cout << num[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do it in a different way? Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read word by word, not line by line, and you need to check that you read a number successfully before storing it.

Right now, you're only trying the first word on the line, and failing.

Try this one:

```
string word;
while (ist >> word) {
    istringstream text(word);
    int integer;
    if (text >> integer)
    {
        num.push_back(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that `text >> integer` isn't a perfect test if `word` is an integer. Better to forget istringstream and use `stoi` or something similar.

Comment: @john but how to make sure that the number in string is the integer?

Comment: Use `stoi` as I suggested (that's not the only way however).